# Get transaction history of customer authorize.net/payflowpro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize.net, payflowpro

We have a developed a web application which integrates with both Authorize.net and PayflowPro gateway. What the client needs is to get the entire transaction history made for that customer in gateway. We are having name, email in common for both the gateway whereas ReferenceTransactionID for PayflowPro and CIM/PaymentProfileID for authorize.net. Is it possible to get all the transaction made for that customer through gateway?

Comment: For ANET, it's only possible if you have the transaction id for each of the customer's transactions.  And the history only goes back 3 years.

Comment: Thanks. I know it. But I want to get the all transaction made for particular customer in the gateway. I tried contacting the support and they said there is no possibility of such thing.